# Is it OK to derive from std::enable_shared_from_this and an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am writing a class that should derive from an abstract base class. I cannot change the abstract base class. The class will be held as a `shared_ptr` to the abstract base class. Is it OK to inherit from the abstract base class *and* [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)? Like this:

```
class IWidget {
public:
  virtual ~IWidget(){}
  // ...
};

class Widget : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Widget>, public IWidget {
protected:
  Widget();  // protected, use create
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<IWidget> create() {
    return std::shared_ptr<IWidget>(new Widget(init));
  }
  // ...
};
```

More complete code [here](http://ideone.com/DIxSAv) that *seems* to work.

Most of the examples I can find of `enable_shared_from_this` have it on the base class. In this case I can't change the base class. Is it OK to use multiple inheritance and use it on the derived class?

I was a bit worried that I could only guarantee `enable_shared_from_this` would only work if I created a `shared_ptr<Widget>` but in this case I'm creating a `shared_ptr<IWidget>`.

**Update:** One interesting thing I noticed is that if I change the `create` method to:

```
  IWidget* w = new Widget(init);
  return std::shared_ptr<IWidget>(w);
```

I get a runtime error when I try and use `shared_from_this()`. I think this makes sense. `shared_ptr` has [a templated constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that takes a "convertible" pointer. And unless the `shared_ptr` constructor knows it is taking a `Widget` it doesn't know it derives from `enable_shared_from_this` and it can't store a `weak_ptr`. I just wonder if this behaviour is documented.

Comment: Shouldn't you inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<IWidget>`, so that `Widget::shared_from_this()` returns `std::shared_ptr<IWidget>` (which you want to work with) rather than `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` (which you currently get)?

Comment: @user4815162342 The primary aim is to capture the `shared_ptr<Widget>` in a lambda created from within `Widget` to ensure the lifetime of the `Widget` is as long as the lambda. From within that lambda I may wish to call local member functions not available on `IWidget`.

Comment: I think it should be ok, as long the `Widget` has no special handling for de-allocation where the resources are not cleaned up in the destructor.

Comment: There's no *the* base class. No problem to use `enable_shared_from_this` in a multiple-inheritance situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely fine.

> `shared_ptr` has a templated constructor that takes a "convertible" pointer. And unless the `shared_ptr` constructor knows it is taking a `Widget` it doesn't know it derives from `enable_shared_from_this` and it can't store a `weak_ptr`.

Exactly right.

> I just wonder if this behaviour is documented.

In the current standard `enable_shared_from_this` is very poorly specified, but see [P0033](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0033r0.html) for the new and improved specification of `enable_shared_from_this` which will be in C++17. As well as answering the "what happens if you do it twice?" question, the revised wording specifies exactly how the `enable_shared_from_this` base class is used, and how the `weak_ptr` member is initialized. That part of the new wording is just standardising existing practice, i.e. it is just a more accurate description of what real implementations already do. (The answer to the "what happens if you do it twice?" question deviates from what implementations previously did, but for good reasons, and that isn't relevant to your question anyway).

The new spec clarifies that your original example is entirely well-defined and correct.

The current standard says that the modified version in your updated question has undefined behaviour when you call `shared_from_this()`, due to violating the precondition that there is `shared_ptr` that owns the pointer-to-derived (because you create a `shared_ptr` that owns the pointer-to-base). However, that precondition is not sufficient to ensure sensible semantics, as explained in the paper. The revised wording makes your modified version also well-defined (i.e. no undefined behaviour) but the `weak_ptr` in the base class will not share ownership with the `shared_ptr<IWidget>` and so `shared_from_this()` will throw an exception (which is what you observe from your implementation).

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  It will be fine, *provided* nobody is relying on undefined behaviour. Now, strictly speaking, your code is already broken if you use UB but in practise multiple inheritance makes a lot of the invalid assumptions that people make more obvious.

I am particularly thinking of

```
Base* p = this;
Derived* pDerived = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(p);
```

May not work as expected. It needs to be `static_cast`.

Comment: This is far from what the OP is asking. And your example has a  well-defined behavior.

Comment: If there is multiple inheritance involved, and Base is not the first base class of Derived, I don't think it does have well-defined behaviour.  Can you offer chapter and verse for it doing so?

Comment: My point was that enabled_shared_from_this works fine in multiple inheritance (which is what the OP asked about), but multiple inheritance can expose invalid assumptions.